# How == works on c++ list iterator?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, comparison-operators

I am wondering, how operator == works on list::iterator. I have list of pointers (there are no duplicities) and two iterators which should point to the same place in that list. When I compare directly iterators by == (or !=) I got inequality but when I compare values they are pointing to I got equality. I also tried `list.erase` on both of then and got the same result.

Example:

```
list<VirtVertex *> blockList;

void initBlockList(){
    /* somehow fill blockList */
    for(auto it = blockList.begin(); it != blockList.end(); ++it)
         (*it)->BLPosition = it;
}

for(auto it = blockList.begin(); it != blockList.end(); ++it){
    if(it == (*it)->BLPosition)
        cout << "OK";  //no "OK" printed
    if(*it == *((*it)->BLPosition))
        cout << "OK";  //got "OK" everytime
}
```

Comment: Please show a demonstrative program that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering, how operator == works on list::iterator.

`operator==` on a `list::iterator` works as you would expect: it returns true if the iterators points to the same element in the same position in the list, or they are both `end`s.

> When I compare directly iterators by == (or !=) I got inequality but when I compare values they are pointing to I got equality.

That's perfectly valid, given that an `std::list` can contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Two iterators compare equal if they point to the same element of the same container (or to the end).    That is as true for all containers, including `list`.

Comparing values that the iterators point to or reference is not the same as comparing iterators.  For a container like `list` that can contain multiple (duplicate) elements with the same value, two iterators may compare unequal, but the values they reference may be the same.    Obviously, if two iterators compare equal, and they are not an end iterator, the values they reference will also compare equal (assuming the element/type has an appropriate comparison operator).

`list.erase()` invalidates existing iterators of a `list`, so using previously obtained iterators gives undefined behaviour.  However, new iterators subsequently obtained from the list will have the same properties.